# Language - automatic and by user

Tags: php, html, forms, html-select

I´m trying to play around with languages and an own Database/CMS structure. I´ve got so far, that the Browserset language is selected. This works well. I know there are better solutions (other domains for each language, i´ve google´d a lot)...with an own added cookie (setcookie) it worked, too.

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

$langCookie = $_COOKIE['language'];

if(!empty($langCookie)){
    $lang = $_COOKIE['language'];
}  

if($lang == en){
//Select from database, got three languages, text (en), textOther1 (otherlang1) and textOther2
}elseif($lang == xy){
//other selecet
}else{
//select if nothing fits
}
```

My problem at this point is:

How can I let the user choose a language with a select on the page.  I want to let the user choose the language by a select...but i can´t get it done to set my cookie as I selected an option...

I know that I have got to reload the page after this (header_location), but I can´t get further...

Any help or tipps for solving this would be very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the GET method to sent request to a page, just add the language code as a paramter, then check whether this parameter exists -- if not, take your value as it's now.

You can use this markup for example:

```
<form id="langForm" action="" method="GET">
    <select name="lang" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Then on-server side you should check if lang parameter exists:

```
<?php

if( isset( $_GET ) && ! empty( $_GET['lang'] ) ) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}

?>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That looks like it could help me! Thanks for your time. I´ll try it and accept it as I can. +1

Comment: Thanks, this is EXACTLY what I was searching. seems to work so far. I can´t do more than to thank you and upvote one time...